# random integer values that collectively cancel each other out

Tags: python-3.x, random, pytorch

In `Pytorch`, I want to generate 50 random integer values that collectively cancel each other out.
After searching, I found this piece of code and it works correctly:

```
torch.manual_seed(71) # to obtain reproducible results
e = torch.randint(-8,9,(50,1),dtype=torch.float)
print(e.sum())
```

output:

```
tensor(0.)
```

Does any one know how it works correcltly and if I want to use some other module like `Numpy`, How can i set the seed for having an array with random numbers that cancel each other out?

Comment: "random numbers that cancel each other out"....  does this mean, sum to zero ?

Comment: if the sum must equal zero *exactly* then you only have 49 random variables, and the 50th is fixed given all other 49.

Comment: Thanks. Maybe i couldn't tell my question correctly. How the code i mentioned, works correctly? Does it any way for set the seed in order to achieve zero summation?

Comment: The code above DOES NOT produce the correct result in general. As it happens, when you set the random seed to 71, the FIRST set of random outputs sums to 0, but future sets of random numbers do not necessarily. This can be proven by re-running the 2nd and 3rd lines without resetting the seed.

Comment: If you are running a cell and set a seed for it, it would be generated the same result whether you run it multiple times, but my question is about setting the number of seed and the way of calculating the seed number.

Answer (score 0):

If the sum must equal zero **exactly**, you only have 49 random variables, and the 50th is determined by the other 49:

```py
e = torch.randint(-8,9,(50,1),dtype=torch.float)  # 50 random variables - the sum is not necessarily 0
e[-1,:] = -e[:-1,:].sum(dim=0)  # last element is no longer random. but the sum is zero
```